# Extracting numbers before colon

Tags: c++, strings

I need to extract all numbers before a colon in a string, e.g.:

- abc1234:blah -> 1234
- 5n63:124 -> 63
- stringwithnocolon -> ""
- stringwith:nonumber -> ""

Limitations:

- no external dependency (looking forward to keep it simple)
- no << operator allowed
- *not* C++11

Here is the code I came up with:

```
const std::string DNAStorage::get_block(const std::string& name)
{
    char* buffer = new char[name.size()];
    char* temp = new char[name.size()];
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == ':')
            break;

        buffer[i] = name[i];
    }

    if (i == name.size())
        return ""; // : not found, cannot be done

    for (j = i - 1; i > 0; j--)
    {
        if (!isdigit(buffer[j]))
            break;

        temp[i - j - 1] = buffer[j];
    }

    temp[i - j - 1] = '\0';

    std::string result = std::string(temp);
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

But I don't really like it. How could I make this code better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jamal's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/75742/32360) already covers some of this, but I wanted to provide slightly different reasons for some of his advice.

**1. Return an `std::string` rather than a `const std::string`.**

Returning an `std::string` makes your function more useful to a caller because it gives them more options.

They can do this:

```
std::string s1 = DNAStorage::get_block ("abc1234:blah") ;
```

Or this:

```
const std::string s1 = DNAStorage::get_block ("abc1234:blah") ;
```

Or even this:

```
const std::string &s1 = DNAStorage::get_block ("abc1234:blah") ;
```

Unless you are trying to force some kind of interface onto the caller, there isn't really any good reason (from a programming perspective) to return a `const std::string`.

**2. Cut down on copying.**

You copy a substring of `name` into `buffer`, then a substring of `buffer` into into `temp`, and then you copy `temp` into `result`. This is unnecessary. See section 4 of this post for an example that avoids all of this copying.

**3. Avoid memory leaks and focus on [exception safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853243/c-do-you-really-write-exception-safe-code).**

You dynamically allocate memory for two character arrays. If you actually needed a buffer (which you don't), you could just do something like this:

```
std::string buffer (name.size (), ' ') ;
```

**4. Here's an example using [std::find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and iterators.**

*Edit:* [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) was kind enough to provide a more concise version:

```
std::string DNAStorage::get_block (const std::string &name)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter ;

    iter colon = std::find (name.begin (), name.end (), ':') ;

    if (colon == name.end ()) { 
        return "";
    }

    iter start = colon ;

    while (start != name.begin () && std::isdigit (*(start - 1))) { 
        --start ;
    } 

    return std::string (start, colon) ;
}
```

Test cases:

```
int main ()
{
    const std::string s1 = DNAStorage::get_block ("abc1234:blah") ;
    const std::string s2 = DNAStorage::get_block ("5n63:124") ;
    const std::string s3 = DNAStorage::get_block ("nocolon") ;
    const std::string s4 = DNAStorage::get_block ("nonumber:ffff") ;
    const std::string s5 = DNAStorage::get_block ("5363:124") ;
    const std::string s6 = DNAStorage::get_block ("v32463:124") ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

**5. Here's an example with [std::reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator).**

First we have to create a unary predicate for [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
bool is_not_digit (char c)
{
    return std::isdigit (c) == 0 ;
}
```

And here's how we can code the function:

```
std::string DNAStorage::get_block (const std::string &name)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator const_iterator ;
    const const_iterator colon_position = std::find (name.begin (), name.end (), ':') ;

    if (colon_position == name.end ()) {
        return "" ;
    }

    std::reverse_iterator <const_iterator> rstart (colon_position) ; 
    std::reverse_iterator <const_iterator> rend = std::find_if (rstart, name.rend (), is_not_digit) ; 

    std::string out (rstart, rend) ;
    std::reverse (out.begin (), out.end ()) ;
    return out ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- There's no need to return as `const`.  A value is still being returned, so it won't make any difference as it can still be modified.
- In C++, unlike in earlier versions of C, there's no longer a need to have loop counter variables declared outside of the loop statements.  Having them all inside will also reduce clutter a bit.
- Unless you really need `buffer` and `temp` to be C-strings, just make them `std::string`.  Otherwise, you must also use `delete[]` on them after they're no longer needed in order to prevent memory leaks from occurring.

Comment: Returning a const string is part of the style guide I'm following, actually.

Comment: @NacibNeme: Okay.  It's not a big deal anyway.

Comment: @NacibNeme: Are you sure. I think you may be misreading the style guide. Or it is a very bad guide as I would consider that dangerous because it gives a false sense of security.

Comment: Oh nvm, it says the parameters should be const not the return values, hehe, so I will get rid of it.

Comment: @NacibNeme: I hope it says the **reference** parameters should be const. Parameters passed by value need not be const (unless you are trying to show something strange).

Comment: Yes, references: "Whenever possible, have function parameters be of type const std::string& and not std::string".

Answer (score 2):

No need for the const:

```
   const std::string DNAStorage::get_block(const std::string& name)
// ^^^^^
```

It has no meaning here.

Dynamically allocating the buffer is a bad idea.

```
    char* buffer = new char[name.size()];
    char* temp = new char[name.size()];
```

You don't actually call delete on these so you are leaking memory. Even if you did call delete the code is still not exception safe. Basically you should never be doing something like this.

```
    std::vector<char>  buffer(name.size());  // This basically does the same as the
    std::vector<char>  temp(name.size());    // above without leeking and being exception
                                             // safe. Also no need to change any
                                             // following code as it will still work
                                             // work in exactly the same way.
```

One variable declaration per line please.

```
    size_t i, j;
```

Also  `i` and `j` are absolutely awful names for variables. Make them readable. Try and search for all occurences of the variable 'i' in the following code.

You can scope the loop variable to the for statement.

```
    for (i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)

    // Can be written like this:

    for (std::size_t loop = 0; loop < name.size(); ++loop)  // prefer prefix ++ (more effecient in some situations).
                              // If you always use the prefix version
                              // you don't need to know which they are
                              // and it future proofs the code.
```

Always use the '{}' to surround a statement block. This will save your ass one day when you use a crappy macro the expands into several statements.

```
        if (name[i] == ':')
            break;

        // Better like this:

        if (name[i] == ':') {
            break;
        }
```

Seems to be a bug here:

```
    for (j = i - 1; i > 0; j--)
```

Can you spot it with those small variable names that look exactly the same.